# Cannot install spree gem - ERROR: invalid gem: package is corrupt

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nokogiri, spree

I'm trying to install the Spree gem, but it's giving me this error:

```
 gem install spree
Fetching: httparty-0.13.3.gem (100%)
When you HTTParty, you must party hard!
Successfully installed httparty-0.13.3
Fetching: highline-1.6.21.gem (100%)
Successfully installed highline-1.6.21
Fetching: friendly_id-5.0.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed friendly_id-5.0.4
Fetching: font-awesome-rails-4.2.0.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed font-awesome-rails-4.2.0.0
Fetching: ffaker-1.25.0.gem (100%)
Successfully installed ffaker-1.25.0
Fetching: polyglot-0.3.5.gem (100%)
Successfully installed polyglot-0.3.5
Fetching: colorize-0.7.3.gem (100%)
Successfully installed colorize-0.7.3
ERROR:  Error installing spree:
    invalid gem: package is corrupt, exception while verifying: undefined method `size' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError) in /home/tarek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/cache/nokogiri-1.6.4.1.gem
```

I tried to uninstall and reinstall Nokogir again, with the same result.

When I tried `sudo gem install nokogiri` another error happened:

```
ERROR:  Error installing nokogiri:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

        /usr/bin/ruby1.9.1 extconf.rb
/usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mkmf (LoadError)
    from /usr/lib/ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
    from extconf.rb:4:in `<main>'


Gem files will remain installed in /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.4.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/nokogiri-1.6.4.1/ext/nokogiri/gem_make.out
```

Comment: try install `nokogiri` apart other gems

Comment: install `mkmf` module

Comment: Looks like you have system ruby installed. try: `sudo apt-get install ruby-dev` and then `gem install nokogiri`.

Comment: @Surya thanks , Successfully installed nokogiri

Comment: whats `ruby-dev`? Any dependency?

Answer (score 10):

I think RubyGems didn't download the file properly. So, the system is reporting that the gem is corrupt.
Delete /home/tarek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/cache/nokogiri-1.6.4.1.gem and then install the gem again.

```
$ sudo rm /home/tarek/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.1.2/lib/ruby/gems/2.1.0/cache/nokogiri-1.6.4.1.gem

$ gem install nokogiri
```

Comment: Thanks :) I'm not genius.

Comment: From Bangladesh ?? :)

Answer (score 1):

Please make sure you install the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install libxslt-dev libxml2-dev
```

Now try installing Nokogiri. Be aware of `sudo` if you using RVM.

```
sudo gem install nokogiri
```

Hope my answer would be helpful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have the system Ruby installed.

You need to first do:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ruby-dev
```

and then do:

```
$ sudo gem install nokogiri
```

I'd encourage you to use Ruby Version Manager like [RVM](http://rvm.io/) or [rbenv](http://rbenv.org/) for managing Ruby environments instead of using the system Ruby on your development environment.